# Eclipse 2019-09 is taking to longer time to build maven project

Tags: eclipse, maven, build

I am using Eclipse IDE for Enterprise Java Developers.

My configuration are,
Version: 2019-09 R (4.13.0)
Build id: 20190917-120
Maven: apache-maven-3.5.0

In eclipse.ini file added 
-vmargs
-Xms256m
-Xmx1024m

Even checked suspend all validation in preferences
Any idea what else I can do to decrease my build time?

Comment: It's not Eclipse, it's Maven. Therefor, you have to add these VM arguments to the Maven launch configuration (in the _JRE_ tab), not into `eclipse.ini` to give your Maven build more memory.

Comment: Build on plain command line and also use the most recent versions of Maven (current 3.6.3)..

Comment: @khmarbaise What difference does it make when running Maven on plain command line?

Comment: Tried with new Maven 3.6.3 but still facing same issue.

Comment: Resolved this issue with Eclipse 2018-12 and Maven 3.6.3 and by creating new workspace in a very different location very there is no link to my previous workspaces.